# Can we create a sub content element for a parent content element in typo3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Is it possible to create a sub content element for one 
content page.I dont like to call the n number of the sub pages

This my present structure:

```
Main page
    ->Sub Page One
      -> Main content one Sub page One
    ->Sub Page Two
      -> Main content one Sub page Two
And i need like this :
     Main page
        ->Sub Page One
             -> Main content one Sub page One (Child One)
                   -> Sub  content of Main content (Child One Sub Child)
        ->Sub Page Two
             -> Main content one Sub page Two (Child Two)
                   -> Sub  content of Main content (Child Two Sub Child)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to "slide" content over pages. This article has some examples about it http://wiki.typo3.org/Content_Slide

When you use TemplaVoila you should look at the extension `kb_tv_cont_slide` http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/kb_tv_cont_slide

Beside, you can also make a reference to a existing content-element. This can easily done with the "Create Reference" option.